# Delete orphans in a self-join

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

The use case is quite straight. After reviewing the comment table of few millions rows. We realize there are many orphans child-comments.

The following query is not working

```
DELETE c.* FROM `comment` c 
where c.parentId not in (select id from `comment`)
```

It says something like:

Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

Unexpected token. (near "c" at position 7)
Unexpected token. (near "." at position 8)
Unexpected token. (near "*" at position 9)

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1093 - You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause

I understand the problem but can't think of an alternative. I am very bad at SQL

Comment: Whatever you do, test these theories for global updates and deletes on dummy tables

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `left join` for this operation:

```
DELETE c
    FROM comment c  LEFT JOIN
         comment cp
         ON c.parentId = cp.id
    WHERE cp.id IS NULL and c.parentId is not null;
```

Do note:  I think you should be careful.  Do all comments really have a parent that is a comment?

Comment: It seems not quite correct. I replace DELETE by SELECT and it gave way too many (incorrect) records

Comment: @PhamHuyAnh . . . I suspect the issue is that `c.parentId` should not be `NULL`.